# Launch MetaHuman to Magic Leap (Augmented Reality) device

Tags: augmented-reality, unreal-engine4, magic-leap

Inside Unreal Engine I have created a scene with a MetaHuman inside. Now I want to launch this scene to a MagicLeap device. This works quite well, but the MetaHuman is not completely rendered. Only the trowsers and the hair of the MetaHuman are rendered correctly, but the complete body of the MetaHuman is missing.

Magic Leap device: ML One Creator Edition
Unreal Engine: 4.26

Do you have a solution or a hint for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile platforms have some limitations. For MetaHumans to work on them the DefaultEngine.ini file needs to be modified. Add Compat.MAX_GPUSKIN_BONES=75 under [ConsoleVariables].

```
[ConsoleVariables]
Compat.MAX_GPUSKIN_BONES=75
```

For Unreal Engine version 4.26 i would also recommend to add

```
fx.Niagara.ForceLastTickGroup=1
```

Refer to https://docs.metahuman.unrealengine.com/en-US/MetahumansUnrealEngine/RequirementsAndConfigSettings/ for more information.